# To show that $f$ is an orthogonal linear map, if $f(0) = 0$ and $f$ preserves the distance

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, inner-products

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional inner product space, and $f:V\to V$ be a map such that $f(0) = 0$ and $\forall x,y\in V$, $||f(x) - f(y)|| = ||x-y||$. Show that $f$ is an orthogonal linear map.

I've been able to show only a part of what's required, and my work is as follows:

Since $||f(x) - f(y)|| = ||x-y||$ holds for all $x,y$, put $y=0$. This gives $||f(x)|| = ||x||$ for all $x\in V$. $f:V\to V$ is a norm-preserving map, and so it is orthogonal *if it is linear* (proof of this is given at **the end**).

Now, how do I show that $f$ is linear? Is there a nice way of doing this? I'd appreciate any hints.

**Proof** of statement above:
I know that a map $T:V\to W$ is orthogonal if $\forall x,y\in V$, we have $\langle Tx,Ty\rangle = \langle x,y\rangle$. 
$f$ is norm-preserving, so for arbitrary $x,y\in V$, we have $||f(x+y)|| = ||x+y||$ and hence $||f(x+y)||^2 = ||f(x)+f(y)||^2 =  ||x+y||^2$. Expanding, we get $||f(x)||^2 + ||f(y)||^2 + 2\langle f(x),f(y)\rangle = ||x||^2 + ||y||^2 + 2\langle x,y\rangle$ and using $||f(x)||=||x||$ and $||f(y)|| = ||y||$ we get $\langle f(x),f(y)\rangle = \langle x,y\rangle$ as desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's show that
$$
f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y).
$$
We have
\begin{align*}
|| (f(x+y)-f(x))-f(y)||^2&=
||
f(x+y)-f(x)
||^2
+
||f(y)||^2
-2<f(x+y)-f(x),f(y)>\\
&=
2||y||^2 -2<f(x+y),f(y)>+2<x,y>\\
&=
||y||^2 +||x||^2-||x+y||^2+2<x,y>\\
&=0
\end{align*}
since
$$
||f(x+y)-f(y) ||^2=||x+y||^2 + || y||^2 -2<f(x+y),f(y)>=|| x||^2.
$$
Using, the same method we have
$$
f(\lambda x)= \lambda f(x).
$$
Indeed, we have
$$
|| f(\lambda x)- \lambda f(x) || ^2=
2\lambda^2||x ||^2-\lambda<f(\lambda x),f(x)> 
$$
but
$$
||f(\lambda x)-f(x) ||^2=|| (\lambda -1)x||^2=(\lambda -1)^2||x||^2
=
(\lambda^2+1)||x||^2 - 2<f(\lambda x),f(x)>
$$
so
$$
2\lambda||x||^2
=
- 2<f(\lambda x),f(x)>
$$
thus
$$
2\lambda^2||x||^2
=
- 2\lambda<f(\lambda x),f(x)>.
$$
So
$$
|| f(\lambda x)- \lambda f(x) || ^2=
2\lambda^2||x ||^2-2\lambda^2||x||^2=0.
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

All isometry can be written as
$$f(v)=\ell(v)+b,$$
where $\ell:V\to V$ is a linear map.

Comment: This isn't something I have proved yet. How do I do this? I don't want to run into something circular.

Comment: Suppose $f(0)=0$. Then using the fact that $f$ is orthogonal yields $|f(x+y)-f(x)-f(y)|^2=\left<f(x+y)-f(x)-f(y),f(x+y)-f(x)-f(y)\right>=0$. Same for $|f(\lambda x)-\lambda f(x)|$. Then $f$ is linear. If $f(0)\neq 0$, do the same with $h(x)=f(x)-f(0)$. @strawberry-sunshine

Answer (score 1):

For any $x$ and $y$ in $V$, $(x+y)/2$ is the unique $z\in V$ such that $\|z-x\| = \|z-y\|= \|x-y\|/2$.  Since $f$ is an isometry, $\|f(z) - f(x)\| = \|f(z) - f(y)\| = \|f(x)-f(y)\|/2$, therefore $$f((x+y)/2) = (f(x) + f(y))/2$$  The case $y=0$ gives us $f(x/2) = f(x)/2$
so we have $$f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$$
Next prove that $f(n x) = n f(x)$ for any integer $n$, then for rational numbers,
then (by continuity) for reals.