# All isometries $f:V\to V$ can be written as $f = T_u\circ A$ - proof of uniqueness?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality, isometry

> Let $f:V\to V$ be an isometry on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$. Then there exists a unique $u\in V$, and a unique orthogonal operator $A:V\to V$ such that $f = T_u\circ A$. This helps conclude that all isometries on $V$ can be written in this form.

I will denote the *translation map* which sends all $v\in V$ to $v+u\in V$ by $T_u$, i.e. $T_u(v) = u+v$.

Using [this post as a Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3933071/to-show-that-f-is-an-orthogonal-linear-map-if-f0-0-and-f-preserves-th), we see that the map $f - f(0)$  is orthogonal. Let's say $u = f(0) \in V$. So, $f-f(0) = T_{-u}\circ f = A$ where $A$ is an orthogonal map on $V$. So we have $f = T_u\circ A$.

How do I **prove the uniqueness** of $u\in V$ and $A\in\mathcal{L}(V,V)$?

Usually, we work with cases where we have to show the uniqueness of only one of the variables, however, it's a little confusing here since we have to show the uniqueness of $u$ and $A$ both. To begin, I would assume that the isometry $f$ on $V$ can be written as $f = T_{u_1}\circ A_1 = T_{u_2}\circ A_2$ for some $u_1,u_2\in V$ and orthogonal $A_1,A_2\in\mathcal{L}(V,V)$. What next?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f = T_{u_1} \circ A_1 = T_{u_2} \circ A_2$, then we have
$$
f(0) = T_{u_1}(A_1(0)) = T_{u_1}(0) = u_1,
$$
and similarly $f(0) = T_{u_2}(0) = u_2$. Thus, $u_1 = u_2$. From there, we have
$$
A_1 = T_{u_1}^{-1} \circ f = T_{u_2}^{-1} \circ f = A_2.
$$

Comment: Could you remind me why $A_1(0) = 0$?

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine $A_1$ is a linear map. So, $A_1(0 \cdot \mathbf 0) = 0 \cdot A_1(\mathbf 0) = \mathbf 0$.